# How to use an array sent with an jQuery's AJAX post request + php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array in an ajax request, but apparently it doesn't work...

```
        $.post("process.php", array,
            function(data) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.parse(data);
            });
```

My question is, how to use the data sent in the process file?
The array is built like that: `[key (0/1/2...)] => ["prod_id"]`. The id varies.
I read somewhere using `$_POST["key"];` would work, but it doesn't.

It'd be even better if I could just get the array **as is** in the process file.

`process.php` (really basic - just to check wether it's working or not.):

`<?php 
    print($_POST["test"]); 
?>`

Comment: I don't know about sending array with jQuery but the $_POST variable would work. When you pass, you should get like `$_POST['key'][0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive data in php you need to send key/value pairs, however you are only sending a value.

You receive in php with `$_POST[key]` which will return the value for that key.

JS:

```
$.post("process.php", {myAray: array}, function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
});
```

php

```
   $array= $_POST['myArray'];
```

To return this array from php as text just to test your ajax  can use `var_dump( $_POST)` or `var_dump($array);`

If you intend to receive JSON in response from server, you do not need to use JSON.parse , jQuery will parse json internally. However you would need to add "json" as dataType argument to $.post

```
$.post("process.php", {myAray: array}, function(data) {
            /* loop over json here*/
},'json');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to build an Object of array elements. for example:

You can also try like:

```
{ 'key[]': [1, 2, 3] }
```

**OR**

```
{ key: [1,2,3] }
```

Read more about **[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass `{data: array}` instead of `array`. The AJAX call expects an object.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass an array, you have to "prepare" the key as following:

```
{'key[]' : ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```

the same way you'd do it, when you want to pass an array in a form and set the name-attribute to "key[]".

Comment: no disrespect … bro. you were mentioning it while i was writing my post. do you feel better when i delete my post?

Comment: Just fine, never do that, I don't bother